How to use AWS EFS for Java file writing
We have Java program which writes into a file at runtime using printwriter. We want to use AWS EFS here. How to use AWS EFS for Java file writing. Could not find any sample code for this functionality. Any help is highly appreciated.

You mount EFS as an NFS disk volume on whatever server your software is running on. Your Java code just needs to write to the path that the EFS volume is mounted to.
That's the only way to write to EFS. There is no method to write directly to an EFS volume via the AWS API/SDK.
